# How to browse a text file & add items to listbox c#/.net

Tags: c#, listbox, file-browser, filebrowse

I want to add items to a "listbox" from a text file by browsing the file that contains text like this:

> "one"
>
> "two"
>
> "three"
>
> "many more"

Please tell me how to browse a text file & add items to a listbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt"))
{
   listbox.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: yes i want to select file by user like we save or open file from any location.
i want to browse file using textbox that contain file path or a button that select a file.

Comment: Then check the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984392(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The code below reads a file and places the text line by line into the Listbox

```
   ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("Path to File");

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        lb.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }

    sr.Close();
```